# Replace a line using sed command

Tags: text-processing, sed

There is a file `sample.txt`. The contents of this file is

```
..some content...
### [http]
# [http]
```

So I have to remove the `#` before `[http]` so that final modified file would look like

```
..some content...
### [http]
[http]
```

I want to do it with the `sed` command. So what will be the exact command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
sed -i 's/^# //' file1
```

So it will search for `#` and a space at the start of each line and replace with null.

If you only want to replace `# [http]` with `[http]`, then use

```
sed -i 's/^# \[http]/[http]/' file1
```

Comment: Better use `'s/^# \[http\]/[http]/'` or you'll remove the `#` from other lines also

Comment: Agreed. Edited the answer to accommodate this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

***sed*** approach, removes `#` only before `[http]` substring:

```
sed -i 's/^# *\(\[http]\)/\1/' file
```

The output:

```
..some content...
### [http]
[http]
```

---

`\1` - points to the first captured group `(...)`

Comment: It's not replacing the content of the file but prints the replaced file on terminal

Comment: @AshishDoneriya, to modify the file add `-i` option

Comment: I've tried that, not working

Comment: @AshishDoneriya, check your code for errors, it works fine for your current input

Comment: No its not working.

Comment: @AshishDoneriya, show your `sed --version`

Comment: sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Comment: Answer provided by Utsav is working.

Comment: @AshishDoneriya, so, it indeed working. You have got confused with your errors, perhaps with braces/quotes